# QEMU doesn't support spice OpenGL

Tags: drivers, graphics, kvm-virtualization, opengl, amdgpu

I'm trying to use KVM on my machine (threadripepr 2950 CPU and AMD WX7100 GPU) running ubuntu 18.04.
I have followed KVM and virtual machine manager and bridge networking procedure and first step was ok.
I have an issue of using OpenGL ( by selecting the option on Display Spice setting).
I found this webpage explained the steps for activation openGL. 
[qemu-kvm](https://at.projects.genivi.org/wiki/display/GDP/QEMU+with+hardware+graphics+acceleration)

Apart of the last step of verification which is:

`# dmesg | grep gl` 
 I cannot see this result : virgl 3d acceleration enabled
the rest of the result was ok.
Would anyone please let me know how I can use and set properly openGL and graphic acceleration on KVM on ubuntu 18.04?

Cheers

Comment: You are using a custom buiild of qemu? The page you linked says you need a custom build to enable _virgl_.

Comment: I used the first part of the solution in this tutorial to resolve my first issue of installing VM using Virtual Machine Manager. I used Virtual Machine Manager for VM creating and setting. one Display Spice section, I checked OpenGL and this cause a problem.

Comment: `Unable to complete install: 'unsupported configuration: This QEMU doesn't support spice OpenGL`

Comment: Yes, as it states at the top of the link you provided: _Sadly, QEMU packages shipped inside distributions don't include support for this : it is thus necessary to compile a custom build which will support this functionality. This page shows how to create such a build and run the GDP image while using a custom QEMU._

Comment: So does that mean there is no other solution to solve this issue on ubuntu? I have problem on that last PATH section actually and i don't know what that means

Comment: Yes. Support for _virgl_ is not built into the default package in the distribution. I don't know why that is. So the immediate solution is that one needs to make a custom built package of QEMU to get Virgl support.

Comment: To support it in the distribution itself the virtgl bits need to pass a security review first (See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virglrenderer/+bug/1657409)